# `searchTwitter`: difference between space and + in the searchString argument

Tags: r, twitter

I'm using `searchTwitter` function in `r`. This function performes a search of Twitter based on a supplied search string. I would like to know what is the difference between space and + in the searchString argument. In other words, do

```
searchTwitter("world cup", n=20000, lang='en')
```

and

```
searchTwitter("world+cup", n=20000, lang='en')
```

produce the same result?

Comment: Have you tried, and did you observe any differences? Chances are it might produce the same result, depending on how it interprets the search phrase.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/twitteR/versions/1.1.9/topics/searchTwitter), you may use `+` to separate the search terms.
From that, I believe that `"world+cup"` would produce different results than `"world cup"`, as the latter would search for the combination, while the former searches for both `world` and `cup`.